# Detecting discontinuities in derivatives in images

Tags: image, distributions, image-processing

Considering an grey-scale image as a function $z=f(x,y)$. (Specifically, I'm interested in $f=h*h*...*h$, where $h$ is the indicator function of a regular hexagon.) I am interested in finding places where $f$ fails to be smooth (or $k$-times continuously differentiable). This is the [Singular Support](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularSupport.html) of $f$.

Is there anything more sophisticated than applying GradientFilter a number of times - and the singular support will show up as white lines.

Edit: As requested here are some pictures for $h*h$. First, the function $h*h$:
[image: h*h]
and now applying the gradient filter:
[image: GradientFilter[h*h]]

I'll try knocking up three for $h*h*h$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as currently posed, it is really about image processing methodology and not about the use of _Mathematica_ ,

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but it would help if you would provide sample images and a minimal working example of your suggested `GradientFilter` approach. Hopefully, together with a little discussion on why it's not a full solution or where it breaks down.

Comment: How about migrating this to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without the Mathematica code involved it seems difficult to reproduce the OP results

Comment: @m_goldberg Trying to close it ... again